# Why do we say -$11\div 3$ is $-4$ with remainder $1$, instead of $-3$ with remainder $-2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

In the book `Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8e, Kenneth Rosen` the quotient and remainder when $-11$ is divided by $3$ are specified as $-4$ and $1$ respectively.  I would appreciate some help in understanding how we got there.  It doesn't gel well with what I was taught in my elementary school.

Specifically, since $-11=(-3)\times 3+(-2)$, why do we not say that the quotient is $-3$ and the remainder is $-2$?

Comment: $-11= ((-4) \times 3 )+1$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I want to know why not ((−3)×3)-2

Comment: You can: see [Remainder: Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Examples)

Comment: In a more advanced setting one might treat "remainders" of $+1$ and $-2$ modulo $3$ as equal (literally, elements of the same equivalence class of *residues*).  But in doing basic arithmetic one must adopt a convention to get a single result, and the simplest convention is to get the remainder $r$ on dividing by $b$ such that $0\le r \t b$.  So following that convention (as many authors will), we chose the quotient that gives that nonnegative remainder.  Something is wrong in your subject line BTW, as $11 \div 3$ should be quotient $3$ with remainder $2$.  Apparently a minus sign was omitted?

Answer (score 1):

What were you taught in elementary school that goes against it? Almost everywhere, this division rule is formally introduced with the name of **Euclid's Division** as follows:

> Given two integers $a$ and $b$, with $b ≠ 0$, there exist unique
> integers $q$ and $r$ such that
>
> $$ a = bq + r $$ and
>
> $$0 ≤ r < |b|$$,
> $$q = \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$$

The above statement is taken from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).

Specifically, in your case,

- a = -11
- b = 3
- q = -4 = floor(a/b)
- r = 1

I guess you hadn't noticed these constraints on the parameters of the equation. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Dividend$=$Divisor$\times$Quotient +Remainder

Dividend $=-11$, Divisor$=3$, Quotient $=-4$, Remainder $=1$

$$-11=(3)(-4)+1$$
Edit: When you divide a number by another number, we get two different remainder values one of them being negative. In your case, remainder can be $1$ as well as $-2$(as $1-3=-2$)

Comment: I want to understand **why not** -11=(3)(−3) - 2

Comment: Do you know concept of negative remainder$?$